# Perforce : Getting user <username> doesn't exist after running "p4 sync" command from console

Tags: console, perforce, command-prompt, p4v, perforce-client-spec

I tried running following command through console and got an error

Command : p4 sync //depot/somepath/ [Event tried with -u < username >]

Error : User < username > doesn't exists.

Same thing is working fine with perforce visual client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to do some p4 configurations such as:

```
 P4PORT
 P4USER
 P4PASSWD
 P4CLIENT
```

First, run the following in your terminal:

```
p4 info
```

Verify if the information match the same info that you have in the GUI version.

Then set the credentials for the followings (In my case I only had to set my user and password):

```
p4 set P4PORT=server.example.com:1666
p4 set P4USER=username
p4 set P4PASSWD=password123
p4 set P4CLIENT=client-dev
```

Once you have all your entries set, just type:

```
p4 login
```

Answer (score 0):

On your command prompt check the output of

```
p4 info
```

If you see username not set to your desired value (the same user in P4V client), then do the following

```
export P4USER=<your username>
p4 login
```

Then run the p4 sync command

Comment: In addition to your user name, check this answer for some additional configuration you may need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640366/how-to-connect-perform-sync-with-perforce-on-mac/25646357#25646357

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue and it was due to my windows login being in CAPS and p4 login in small caps.

By default p4 takes login of windows as user if P4USER is not set in the command shell your are using. If your case is same set the p4 login with correct case and you should see the password prompt.